# Not able to multithread ConcurrentHashMap using parallelSteam

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to create `ConcurrentHashMap<String,ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>>` from list using parallel stream.it seems its going into infinite loop or deadlock and never coming out this code. let me if i hv missed something.

lines are like
L1|O1,O2,O3
L2|O1,O2,O3

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> all= (ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>>) lines
.parallelStream()
.collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(line->line.split("\\|")[0],line->{
     return (ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>)Arrays.asList(line.split("\\|")[1].split("\\s*,\\s*"))
     .stream().collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(l->l,l->"400"));
}));
```

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/exQRwm

Comment: Btw, you're making a dangerous assumption by casting the result to `ConcurrentHashMap`. If you want a concrete type, use [the overload that accepts a map `Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toConcurrentMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-).

Comment: yes, But if you put your code in static block. then its not working. could you see once? static{ <code>}

Comment: Hmm, very interesting: http://ideone.com/uMtHu7

Comment: Yes its a duplicate. Thanks shmosel!